# In rails4 having many models, using cancancan gem, grant access to specific user to a specific model only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan

I have 5 models in my rails 4 application, and using cancancan gem I want to give access to specific users to a specific model only.

This means:

- user1 is allowed to access 1,2 model
- user 2 is allowed to access 3,4 model
- user 3 is allowed to access all models.

Please guide me.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Users cannot "access" models. A client making a request of your app interacts with **controllers**. Controllers turn a request into some kind of invocation on your model layer, it's up to you define what that interaction is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler version of `Mike`'s answer would be as follows:

```
#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    case user.role_id
      when 1
         can :read, Model
         can :read, Model2
      when 2
         can :read, Model3
         can :read, Model4
      when 3 
         can, :manage, :all
    end
  end    
end
```

You'll have to add a way to define whether a `User` is `1`,`2`,`3` etc, which is why `Mike` suggested `rolify`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [rolify with cancan](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial) to accomplish that. You can assign a certain role with [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) to represent your "user 1" or "user 2" like this:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.add_role :limited_user_1
```

and your "user 3" that has access to everything can be an admin

```
user = User.find(3)
user.add_role :admin
```

Then with [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) it's as simple as checking if the `user` has the specified `role`. In this case `:manage` means the `user` has access to all actions, such as `:read`, `:create`, `:update`, `:destroy`.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.limited_user_1?
      can :manage, :model_1
      can :manage, :model_2
    elsif user.limited_user_2?
      can :manage, :model_3
      can :manage, :model_4
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the answer I think